# "Too short a time" or "Too short of a time"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, parts-of-speech

What is the correct phrase to be used among these two:

1. Too short a time
   Or
2. Too short of a time

Which one is correct for daily English usage?

Comment: 1) is correct in everyday use. Offhand I can't think of a example where you could use 2) .

Comment: So the first one can be used in spoken English and the second is generally used while writing.

Comment: No, I don't think you would ever use the second one. I've never seen or heard it. Do you have an example of where you have seen the second one used? If so, please add it to your question. The first version is used everywhere.

Comment: You're right. I didn't find any sentence which used the second phrase. I realize that I may have been mixing up the phrases 'short of time' and 'short a time'. Thank you for the response:)

Comment: Actually there is one construct you might come across, something like "You are allowing _too short of a time_ to do that task" meaning "You are not allowing enough time to do that task". I'm not sure where I've seen this, but it can be said.

Comment: You're right @sumelic. Both of them are similar.

Comment: @PeterJennings what is English if not unpredictable!